# What anime is this GIF of a man in a suit running down the stairs from?

Tags: nabari-no-ou

[This anime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyAYj.gif) looks kinda cool but I have no idea what it is.  Thanks in advance ^-^

Answer (score 5):

[image]That's [Tobari Durandal Kumohira](http://nabarinoou.wikia.com/wiki/Tobari_Durandal_Kumohira) from [Nabari no Ou](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=9102).